# Как воспроизвести аудиофайл для страницы ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, mediaplayer

ViewPager показывает ряд изображений, которые перелистываются свайпом. Каким образом можно к каждому изображению "прикрутить" автоматическое воспроизведение аудиофайла? Для каждой картинки свой аудиофайл
Привожу код адаптера:

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] image_resourses = {
            R.drawable.eskiz_1, R.drawable.eskiz_2,
            R.drawable.eskiz_3, R.drawable.eskiz_4};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflatter;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter (Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return image_resourses.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflatter = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflatter.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout,container,false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(image_resourses[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Обрабатываете смену страницы и вешаете включение нужного аудиофайла на это событие.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге остановился на таком варианте, свою задачу решает.

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<String> pagesFiles;
    ArrayList<String> soundsFiles;
    String folderB;

    public CustomSwipeAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<String> pagesFiles, ArrayList<String> soundsFiles, String folderB) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.pagesFiles = pagesFiles;
        this.soundsFiles = soundsFiles;
        this.folderB = folderB;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pagesFiles.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        String nameS = Uri.parse(soundsFiles.get(position)).getLastPathSegment();
        final String soundPath = String.valueOf(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(folderB));
        final Uri souF = Uri.fromFile(new File(soundPath, nameS));
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, souF);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflatter = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert layoutInflatter != null;
        View item_view = layoutInflatter.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        File imgFile = new File(pagesFiles.get(position));
        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            container.addView(item_view);
        }
        item_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.start();
            } else {
                mp.pause();
            }
        }
        });

        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```